# How to derive Probabilities from likelihood ratios when size of set is greater than 2?

Tags: probability, log-likelihood

I am defining a set $\mathbf{Z} = [p,q,r,s]$ such that $Pr(p)+Pr(q)+Pr(r)+Pr(s)=1$.

I have access to the likelihoods that are defined as follows

\begin{align}
 \lambda_p&=\log \frac{Pr(x=p)}{Pr(x=s)}, \hspace{2mm} \lambda_q=\log \frac{Pr(x=q)}{Pr(x=s)}\\[15pt]
 \lambda_r&=\log \frac{Pr(x=r)}{Pr(x=s)}, \hspace{2mm} \lambda_s=\log \frac{Pr(x=s)}{Pr(x=s)}=0
\end{align}

How can I compute $Pr(x=p)$ from this information.

***Note***

For $\mathbf{Z'} = [m,n]$, we have

\begin{align}
 \lambda&=\log \frac{Pr(x=m)}{Pr(x=n)}=\log \frac{Pr(x=m)}{1-Pr(x=m)}\\
\implies Pr(x=m) &= \frac{1}{1+e^{-\lambda}}
\end{align}

I am trying to derive similar expression when size of set is greater than 2.

Comment: You can get the right font for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own (e.g. $\operatorname{Pr}$), you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @joriki $\Pr$ should has its own command :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$
\mathrm e^{\lambda_p}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_q}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_r}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_s}=\frac1{\operatorname{Pr}(x=s)}
$$

and

$$
\mathrm e^{\lambda_p}=\frac{\operatorname{Pr}(x=p)}{\operatorname{Pr}(x=s)}\;,
$$

so

$$
\operatorname{Pr}(x=p)=\frac{\mathrm e^{\lambda_p}}{\mathrm e^{\lambda_p}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_q}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_r}+\mathrm e^{\lambda_s}}\;.
$$